# Try to write quality selenium script in Python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have a csv file with more then 1000 records of website addresses.I write a 140 lines script with functions and try catch of some of the most popular exception in Selenium but still I run into problems like a attribute error or captcha how can I skip this problems and my script to go till the end of that csv file and extract data I need.I use ActionChains method to click desired link location in footer`

```
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(contactpg()[1]).click().perform()`
```

Ps:When I run the script its work for a wile and run into problem in some pages.My question is Do Selenium have some pattern for big list of URL that can pass problem pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle errors as the following sample code:

```
try:
    #something
except Exception as e:
    if 'particular message' in str(e):
        # Do the following
        # if you don't want to stop for loop then just continue
        continue
```

Comment: what do source_checkrefcode() as I see for exceptions  Exception as e is for all of the exceptions in Selenium.Thank you